# I'm trying to use Instagram API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api

I'm using default Instagram API, but when I try to fetch comments on posts, I'm getting a response with data empty, even when I know that there are comments on the post.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/

So when I tried to report it, it told me to migrate to Instagram Graph API.  I searched, its look it's for personal use for business, I was building a raffle website helper, randomly pick a winner from a comment, and this broke my project.

#### Edit 1

So I'm confused because when I access Instagram Developer website says to gonna to new Instagram Graph API, but here, I got a message that it's just for business accounts, but I already have registered my app with "facebook login" like the links you have sent to me

See demo what I'm building: https://youtu.be/DmVN5t0dRaY
The problem: https://imgur.com/a/YHC5lZE

Answer (score 1):

This is deprecated by Instagram. It's not really telling you to use the Graph API, it's saying that this is the way they are going and the Graph API is intended for business that want to maintain their own page and interact more successfully with Instagram users.

Comment: I'm really confused, I don't know what I should choose, because I'm gonna to build a website to do raffle, the user visit my website, do auth with instagram account (doesn't matter for me if this account is business or not, BUT NEED TO SUPPORT EITHER) and after with access_token I fetch the media of user, and the user can chose from your instagram photos what picture wants to raffle a comment

Answer (score 0):

Instagram still offers an endpoint

GET /users/self/media/recent

That should suit your needs.

Comment: This works for get midia, but after I got the media, I need to fetch with details each coment of this selected media